# Getting failed in providing HiltTestApplication as a dependency in my test module

Tags: android, testing, dagger-2, dagger-hilt, instrumented-test

I have followed [this](https://dagger.dev/hilt/testing.html) guide and trying to run instrumented test with HILT.But its getting failed in providing [HiltTestApplication](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/hilt/android/testing/HiltTestApplication.html) as a dependency in my test module.
Below is my module class-

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@FlowPreview
@Module
@TestInstallIn(components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [ProductionModule::class])
object TestModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRecipeDb(app: HiltTestApplication): RecipeDatabase {
        return Room
            .inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(app, RecipeDatabase::class.java)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
    }
}
```

Got below error-

> C:\Users\bhuvn\AndroidStudioProjects\Dairy\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debugAndroidTest\com\bhuvnesh\diary\framework\dataSource\cache\RecipeDaoServiceTests_HiltComponents.java:128:
> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding]
> dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltTestApplication cannot be provided
> without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
> public abstract static class SingletonC implements
> RecipeDaoServiceTests_GeneratedInjector,
> ^
> dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltTestApplication is injected at
> com.bhuvnesh.diary.di.TestModule.provideRecipeDataFactory(application,
> �)
> com.bhuvnesh.diary.framework.dataSource.data.RecipesDataFactory is injected at
> com.bhuvnesh.diary.framework.dataSource.cache.RecipeDaoServiceTests.recipeDataFactory
> com.bhuvnesh.diary.framework.dataSource.cache.RecipeDaoServiceTests is
> injected at
> com.bhuvnesh.diary.framework.dataSource.cache.RecipeDaoServiceTests_GeneratedInjector.injectTest(com.bhuvnesh.diary.framework.dataSource.cache.RecipeDaoServiceTests)
> It is also requested at:
> com.bhuvnesh.diary.di.TestModule.provideRecipeDb(app)

I also tried by manually providing dependency in same module using-

```
    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideHiltTestApplication():HiltTestApplication{
        return HiltTestApplication()
    }
```

But it provides a null object which results in nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 1):

To provide the application context, you need to replace `app: HiltTestApplication` with `@ApplicationContext app: Context` because `HiltTestApplication` is the base application that can be used for Android instrumentation or Robolectric tests using Hilt, but it has to be specified in its annotations ( Like this `@Config(application = HiltTestApplication::class)` ). So, to provide the context in a method, you need to add the predefined qualifier to provide it. Check these out

- https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#predefined-qualifiers
- https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#robolectric-tests